# A script that automatically restores the database in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, batch-file, pg-dump

i already have a backup scripts that run automatically 
i need a script that can restore that exact file that has been backed up it by sorting by the latest backup file

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%i in ('dir "C:\Users\pc\backup_test" /O-D') do (
    set BACKUP_FILE=%%i
    goto :endfor
    )
:endfor
%BACKUP_FILE%
@echo off
```

Comment: if the question is about PostgreSQL then why are MySQL and SQLite also tagged, i removed those tags.

Comment: I assume the command (or script?) that you've included is what you tried to do. What wrong with it as in what does not work as you expected?